# How is jQuerys event.PreventDefault(); done?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn just `Javascript` at the moment, and I'm making a little thing and when I click on the `Anchor` I don't want the page to refresh, I added a `href='#'` but the page still shoots to the top if I'm at the bottom and click on the `Anchor`. I'm trying to avoid this, I tried googling but I can't for the life of me find anything, I googled 'event.preventDefault without jQuery and nothing. Any information would be great, thanks!

Comment: It delegates to the host implementation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault.

Answer (score 4):

`preventDefault` isn't actually a jQuery thing. When you add an event listener, your handler gets an event argument not unlike the jQuery event argument. jQuery simply wraps this to make it more consistent cross-browser, but `preventDefault` exists on the plain, non-jQuery one as well.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('my_link').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // No jQuery needed!
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been using jQuery for a while I figured it's time to put the frameworks away and learn some bare bones, thanks ill accept as soon as I'm able to

Answer (score 0):

It jumps to the top because you tell it to.

Try `href="javascript:;"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add javascript:void(0) into href like this

```
            <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="doSomething()" />
```

With it, you can even make the anchor link run a javascript function if you want.
or just simple

```
            <a href='javascript:void(0)' />
```

You don't need  jQuerys event.PreventDefault(); to deal with that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent navigation is to return false from the click handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" />
```

Answer (score -3):

You're looking for:

```
$("#anchorID").click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

or
    $("#anchorID").click(function(d) {
      d.PreventDefault();
    });

Comment: he's not using jquery.